# ¿Cómo puedo correr bower install en un entorno de Elastic Beanstalk en AWS?

Tags: laravel, nodejs, npm, aws, bower

Tengo un proyecto en `Laravel` con la siguiente estructura de archivos

[image: Estructura de archivos]

Dónde mis archivos `bower.json` y `.bowerrc` son los siguientes:

```
// bower.json
{
    "name": "api",
    "description": "",
    "main": "",
    "authors": [
        "Autor <email>"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "homepage": "",
    "ignore": [
        "**/.*",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "test",
        "tests"
    ],
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap4": "bootstrap#^4.1.3",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "fontawesome": "^5.2.0",
        "select2": "^4.0.5"
    }
}

// .bowerrc

{
    "directory": "public/assets"
}
```

Estoy intentando correr el comando `bower install` para instalar las dependencias de la siguiente manera utilizando el archivo `package.json` de `npm`

```
{   
    ...
    "scripts": {
        ...
        "postinstall": "node_modules/bower/bin/bower install -F"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        ...
        "bower": "^1.8.4"        
    }
}
```

Pero cuando realizo el despliegue con `eb deploy` los assets me devuelven 404

> GET http://DOMINIO/assets/fontawesome/web-fonts-with-css/css/fontawesome-all.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
>   ...
>   ...
>   ...

En mi entorno local todo funciona correctamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solo tenía que hacer uso de [ebextensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html), entonces lo que debía hacer era crear una carpeta en la raíz de mi proyecto llamada `.ebextensions` allí cree un archivo llamado `project.config` con una sintáxis de `YAML` y el siguiente contenido:

```
packages: 
  yum:
    gcc-c++: []
    make: []
    git: []
  commands:
    01_get_sudo:
      command: echo Defaults:root \!requiretty >> /etc/sudoers
    02_npm_install:
      command: sudo yum -y --enablerepo=epel install nodejs npm
    03_npm_config_strict_ssl:
      command: sudo npm config set strict-ssl false
    04_npm_install_bower:
      command: sudo npm install -g bower
  container_commands:
    01_bower_install:
      command: sudo bower install --allow-root
```

Les agregué el prefijo de `0Número` porque a la hora de ejecutar los comandos en la `instancia` el lee el archivo `.config` y ejecuta los comandos de manera alfabetica.

> **NOTA** Tuve que añadir el archivo al control de versiones (git en este caso) porque estaba realizando el `eb deploy` y la carpeta `.ebextensions` no estaba dentro del código desplegado.